Linux: difference between outputs of df -h and du -sh *
I want to understand how much disk space I have left on my virtual machine. I am running df -h and get results. Then to doublecheck I am running du -sh * to see which folders consume the space. I am surprised to see this 2 results do not match! du -sh * gives me 5 GB disk space used. df -h tells me all 20 GB are used. Where is the truth?
Please see attached screen.



Sadly, df -h has right. They work very differently: df -h queries and answers the count of the allocated blocks on the partition, while du -sh recursively travlers a directory tree and summarizes the size of the files found.

You did not ask, but here you have likely yet another question: how can 0 byte left if 19GB is used on a 20GB hard disk. Answer is that filesystems, including ext4, tend to reserve the last percents (5%) for root-only, i.e. that can be allocated only by root processes. You can turn off the feature by a tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sda1 command. That is permanent and does not need an unmount or reboot. After that, you will see the rest of your last about 1GB.

du -sh * is completely incompetent for this task, on multiple reasons. The first reason is that it measures the size of the files allocated in a directory. But, for example, /proc, /run, /dev/shm are mounted filesystems, also they are reachable from the /, where you have executed du -sh *.

Things are yet more bad if anything is under /proc, for example some bad software or funny co-sysadm ;-) placed there a 10GB big file with zeros, that would still count as allocated blocks, but it would not be visible for your df.

Things are also bad that a file can be deleted under Linux even if it is open. This is one of the reasons, why Linux does not need to reboot every tuesday. However, a deleted file only disappears from the directory listing, thus df won't see it any more, but its blocks won't be deallocated. Its blocks will be deallocated only if the last process is closing it. That is the most likely cause of your huge difference.

df -h * shows only the non-hidden root directories, i.e. if you have a directory /.wastebasket, full with 14GB crap, then your command won't see also this. A df -h * .* would show also these hidden files/directories.

You can check the list of the deleted files by the lsof command. If is a very useful tool, it shows all opened files of all processes, including the deleted ones. I suggest to once read its documentation. Well, it is big, I was lazy for that until now :-) rather I use an lsof|grep -i deleted.

You can actually do some like you try to reach with the du -sh *, but it requires more steps. First, mount your root partition again into a temporary mount point: mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/tmp (mkdir /mnt/tmp if it does not exist yet). Then, a du -ba .|sort -n -r|head -100 in /mnt/tmp will show the 100 of your largest files or directories. Trick is that this secondary mount will be "mount-clean". After that, do not forget to un-mount /mnt/tmp.



I estimate the probability of that either lsof, or this du -ba . will solve your problem, to about 99%.

Thank you, peterh! It was about deleted files held by some old processes.

@MiamiBeach Wonderful, in most cases you can just restart a service or that process.
